# Spring boot endpoint returning object including 2 lists of objects

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a simple method

```
public ResponseEntity<List<Item>> findAllByParameters(@RequestBody ListofParameters listOfParameters) {
    log.info("Find All items with given parameter");
    return ResponseEntity.ok(itemRepository.findAllBy(listOfParameters));
}
```

My List of parameters looks like this (for now its only 1 List of strings)

```
@Getter
@Setter
    public class ListofParameters {

    @NotNull
    private List<String> colors;
```

My repository filters the database records with this parameters:

```
public interface ItemRepository extends CrudRepository<Item, String> {

    @Query("SELECT it FROM Item it WHERE (it.color IS NULL OR it.color IN (:#{#listOfParameters.colors}))")
    List<Item> findAllBy(@Param("listOfParameters") ListOfParameters listOfParameters);
}
```

Now I return a full list of objects when parameters match them, or an empty list when they don't.

Analogically if I try find 3 colors and match only two, I will get no information about missing one (just get a list of two objects).

**Problem** is that I would like to know which items are not matched. Figured that good solution would be to return an object holding two lists of objects (one matching the given color and one that don't)

Does anyone has any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> Analogically if I try find 3 colors and match only two, I will get no information about missing one (just get a list of two objects).
>   Problem is that I would like to know which items are not matched.

To know which items are missing,

Assume, in database contains items having a color of ("blue" and "red").
 Your request contains color of ("blue", "red" and "yellow").
 Output you want "yellow" (because database does not have any item with "yellow" color)

```
public void myMethod(){
  ListOfParameters listOfParameters = new ListOfParameters();
  listOfParameters.setColors(Arrays.asList("blue", "red", "yellow"));

   // items with "red" and "blue" would return
  List<item> items =  ItemRepository.findAllBy(listOfParameters);


 // convert List<item> into List<String> having color "red" and "blue" 
 List<String> includeColors =    items.stream().map(Item.getColor()).collect(Collectors.toList());


  // remove common color
  listOfParameters.getColors().removeAll(includeColors)

  o/p  [yellow]


  s.o.p(listOfParameters.getColors());


}
```